# Extending Templates from project root Django

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-templates

In my root folder I have a templates folder, with a base.html file inside of it. I have an app with some html, and I want it to extend base.html.

Here's the code inside base.html:

```
<header><h3>Header here</h3></header>
    {% block content %}
    {% endblock %}
<footer><h3>Footer here</h3></footer>
```

The code inside app is:

```
{% extends base.html %}
{% block content %}
<h1>{{ question.question_text }}</h1>
<ul>
    {% for choice in question.choice_set.all %}
    <li>{{ choice.choice_text }} -- {{ choice.votes }} vote{{    choice.votes|pluralize }}</li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>

<a href="{% url 'polls:detail' question.id %}">Vote again?</a>
{% endblock %}
```

For some reason I'm getting an Invalid template name in 'extends' tag error and I don't know why.

I've updated my settings.py file to this from searching online but still doesn't work:

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

file name should be with in quotes

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block content %}
{% endblock %}
```

in your settings.py should be

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates/')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

Comment: I've updated the template to include the quotes, but now I am getting a TemplateDoesNotExist error. I've included the directory in DIRS as shown above, and I've checked that base.html is located in the expected directory. Any ideas?

Comment: @dobolicious check the latest answer

Comment: Wait don't worry, found out the problem, my templates directory was in the wrong place. Thanks for the help and your time.